# Create a series of dataframes where each data frame is called the name of an iterable list

Tags: python, pandas, csv, naming

I have a feeling this is basic but its late so apologies upfront if its really simple

I have more but for simplicity lets say I have 2 .csv files.
They are neflix.csv and amazon.csv  (each file has a 'date' 'open' 'close' etc)

I could create a dataframe called the same name by opening them each one by one:

```
path = 'C:/Desktop/Python/Project/"netflix.csv"'
netflix = pd.read_csv(path)
path = 'C:/Desktop/Python/Project/"amazon.csv"'
amazon = pd.read_csv(path)
```

I'd like to rather iterate over a list of file names, read from the file and create a dataframe with the same name.

So I'm looking for something like this

```
path = 'C:/Desktop/Python/Project/'
file_list = ['netflix.csv','amazon.csv']

for i in file list:
    file_list[i] = pd.read+csv(path + file_list[i])
```

That obviously doesnt work.  The output in this case should be a dataframe called netflix with whats read from the netflix csv and a dataframe called amazon with the data read from the amazon csv.  However its complicated further by the fact that the name cant be amazon.csv  as there is a "." in it so it needs to be stored as amazon while the file_list[i] is obviously 'amazon.csv'

Comment: Don't do that. Create a dictionary of dataframes with the key as the file name. `df_dict[i] = pd.read_csv(path+i)`

Comment: In this scenario can you show what the expected output looks like, along with what your 2 inputs look look like: you can copy the first 5 lines of your netflix.csv and amazon.csv and show it here, then build manually a dataframe that looks like what you expect (with all the specifications: name of the dataframe, etc) I have edited so you can fill in the template.